# Regex matching text within paragraphs

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match the paragraph that contains a keyword.

Example text:

```
I have a textfile containing text. Each paragraph 
may span multiple lines. 

Paragraphs have a newline between them. I would 
like to match a paragraph that holds some text
and would like to match this line as well.

The regex doesn't have to match the first or last
paragraph (we can assume each paragraph has
newlines around it).
```

Sample keyword: `holds` (so middle paragraph should match).

I tried the following regex: `var regX = /(.+\r?\n)+.*holds.*(?=(\r?\n)?)/igm;`

This matches the first 2 lines (not the last line):

```
Paragraphs have a newline between them. I would 
like to match a paragraph that holds some text
```

Changing `.*holds.*` into `.*holds[\s\S]*` selects too much (selects 2nd and 3rd paragraph in the example) (`.*holds[\s\S]*?` doesn't work either - not greedy enough.)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
^\r?\n(?:.+\r?\n)*.*\bholds\b.*\r?\n(?:.+\r?\n)*(?=\r?\n)
```

Use with `/gm`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK6iK8/1)

Be aware this regeix is subject to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) but there's not much you can do about it in JavaScript, unfortunately.

This pattern basically captures a blank line, followed by some lines (`(?:.+\r?\n)*`), then by a line containing `holds` (`.*\bholds\b.*\r?\n`), then again by 0 or more lines (`(?:.+\r?\n)*`), and finally makes sure the last newline is itself followed by a newline: `(?=\r?\n)`.